# can't run vs 2008 or 2010 on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I just installed windows 7 and because I wish to learn more C/C++ I've tried to install VS 2008 or VS2010 beta. On both of them I get the same message error. I had only one version of each one installed at one time.

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(){
 printf("hello world");
 return 0;
}
```

but when I hit debug, I get the following message:

> Unable to start program 'c:\users....\Debug\helloworld.exe'.
>   The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Comment: Can you compile and then go to the debug directory and run the file directly?

Comment: If I rebuild, I can run it. If i modify the source code, i have to rebuild it again, in order to get the modifications on the executable. Doesn't seems to be right at all!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your problem is more with output file destinations or the `%PATH%` environment variable than Visual Studio -- your .vcproj is depositing the .exe, or some file upon which it depends, where the debugger can't find it.

My first suggestion is to look at the "Debugger" settings of that project's Properties, and make sure that it's running from the correct Working Directory -- that is to say, that its working directory is the same place that the .vcproj is configured to put the compiled .exe.

Answer (score 1):

On VS 2008, Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build & Run -> Choose 'Always Build' for the 'On Run, when projects are out of date:' part. Thats the solution for the same problem of mine

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm you that VS2008 is compatible witn Windows 7. I'm running it now. Check that you have rights to read/write in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with VS 2008 and Windows 7 for the past 4/5 months without any signle issues. Might be some configuration issu?

Looking at the error it seems your program is complied but not able to run(?)